# json problems with making a ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

So I'm using Bitnami to learn Ruby on Rails. I have also previously tried the manual installation for ruby and rails and was met by the same problem so I thought I should try first the easy package deal of Bitnami. Anyway my problem with json is that it causes the bundle install to fail.

First the auto bundle install that rails new does fails because of an ssl error. Which is easily solved by changing the source in the gemfile which is https to http.
However when I try to bundle install it does another error when it tries to install json.

```
C:\RubyStack-3.2.7-0\projects\testing>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using multi_json (1.3.6)
Installing activesupport (3.2.8)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Installing activemodel (3.2.8)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.3)
Installing actionpack (3.2.8)
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Installing actionmailer (3.2.8)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
Installing activerecord (3.2.8)
Installing activeresource (3.2.8)
Using bundler (1.1.5)
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Installing json (1.7.5) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

        C:/RUBYST~1.7-0/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
      0 [main] echo 5244 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to echo.exe.sta
ckdump
make: *** [generator-i386-mingw32.def] Error 5


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RUBYST~1.7-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RUBYST~1.7-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/j
son/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

This is the gem_make.out file it produces after trying to install json (btw windows also produces an error that echo.exe has stopped working while running the gem install json)

```
C:/RUBYST~1.7-0/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
      0 [main] echo 5244 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to echo.exe.stackdump
make: *** [generator-i386-mingw32.def] Error 5
```

I can't even start learning ror for the setup is already a huge pain. (btw I have no prior experience with web frameworks, just desktop programming). help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered dropping bitnami, starting fresh, and going through Michael Hartl's http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?
It will get you set up from the beginning and the price is right (free).

Comment: Yea that's actually the first thing I tried before having to use Bitnami

Comment: I am surprised it didn't work.  Is there anything special about your environment?  I noticed that you are using Windows, and that does make it a bit harder, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Building native extensions.  This could take a while.
`ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /Users/bruceyue001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb`
```

Creating makefile

```
make
compiling generator.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1
```

Gem files will remain installed in `/Users/bruceyue001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.5` for inspection.
Results logged to `/Users/bruceyue001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out`

Answer (score 0):

Running rails on windows requires the installation of DevKit.

Install the DevKit and it should fix your problem:
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Comment: BitNami RubyStack already installs DevKit on Windows systems.